# Generic NSKeyValueObservedChange/Keypath

Tags: swift, keypaths, swift-keypath

I have an array of `NSKeyValueObservation`. I am watching a few properties on a `NSManagedObject` and I want to execute all of the same method when a property changed. This is the code:

```
let completionHandler: ((MyObject, NSKeyValueObservedChange<Any>) -> ()) = { [unowned self] (_, _) in
    self.update(object: object)
}
```

I am trying to apply it like:

```
observers = [
    myObject(\.myProperty, options: .new, changeHandler: completionHandler),
    myObject(\.myProperty2, options: .new, changeHandler: completionHandler),
    ...
]
```

But than I get the error:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

I don't care about the KeyPath, I just want to refresh another view. The properties are all of a different type.